# why can't I use a package in texmaker?

Tags: packages

I am using Texmaker on a mac. I downloaded MacTex. However, I cannot use packages in Texmaker. It always keeps telling cannot find `.sty` file.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you made sure that MacTex can find the LaTeX directory?

Comment: You might want to also post a minimal example so that others can test if loading that package on their system,  works. Did you spell it correctly.

Comment: Does LaTeX work from the Terminal? For example, what do `pdftex --version` and `command -v pdftex` give?